# Saving confusion matrix as an image file

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there a way in matlab to store the results of `plotconfusion (x,y)` to a specified file location as an image file? Like a code version of save as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a figure file, you want to use saveas() ("help saveas"). As an image file, try print() ("help print"). Examples:

```
print(gcf, '-dpng', 'out.png');
saveas(gcf, 'out.fig');
```